# Python, Pandas, convert Timestamp to Period

Tags: python, pandas

Lets consider the following DataFrame:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(dt(2010,1,1), dt(2010,1,31), freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(date_range),2), index = date_range)
```

If I group the datapoints by periods of 1 week and visualize the groups definition, I get:

```
In: [1]:df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups
Out:[1]: 
     {Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 3,
     Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 10,
     Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 17,
     Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 24,
     Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'): 31}
```

I retrieve the keys of that dictionary:

```
In: [2]: list(df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).keys())
Out:[2]: 
    [Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'),
     Timestamp('2010-01-10 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'),
     Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'),
     Timestamp('2010-01-17 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN'),
     Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN')]
```

However I am left with those funny variables such as `Timestamp('2010-01-24 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN')` That have the prefix `Timestamp` but are structured like Periods. How can I convert such values to actual Periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).groups
per = [pd.Period(x, freq=x.freq) for x in a]
print (per)
[Period('2010-01-18/2010-01-24', 'W-SUN'), 
 Period('2010-01-04/2010-01-10', 'W-SUN'), 
 Period('2010-01-25/2010-01-31', 'W-SUN'), 
Period('2010-01-11/2010-01-17', 'W-SUN'), 
Period('2009-12-28/2010-01-03', 'W-SUN')]
```

Comment: But is the variable `Timestamp('2010-01-03 00:00:00', freq='W-SUN')` a correct one or a bug? Why would a timestamp have a freq value attached?

Comment: I think it is correct. But a I not sure if I know nice explain it. But it seem if frequency is changed, fteq is added.